# Node https server secureOptions not working

Tags: node.js, http, ssl

I have a React node app which is using node v.6, everything works fine on it; however I am now trying to disallow TLS1.0 on the https server but am having issues. The app is using https.createServer to run the app over https on port 443. This all works fine and we have ssl working properly with the app.

The issue is when I add in my secureOptions for configuring TSL nothing seems to change. I have tried a number of different methods but every time I run a scan on the site I get the same result. So I don't know if my code is wrong or there is something else at play I am unaware of.

This is currently what my code looks like which I think is correct from what I have researched online (I have also tried without the key and cert options to exactly mimic the examples I saw).

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./keys/example-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./keys/example-cert.pem"),
  secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
  pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./keys/example.pfx")),
  passphrase: PASSPHRASE
};

console.log('Run on https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

To my knowledge this is what I need to have in place for preventing TSL1.0 but like I said I have absolutely zero changes when rescaning my site.

One other thing to note is this app is running on an IIS environment and there is some firewall in place on the server. I am not the one handling the firewall and server stuff so I know little about them but I don't know if that could be a factor in causing this problem.

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated

just for reference this is what my scan looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
const { constants } = require('crypto')

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync("./keys/example-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./keys/example-cert.pem"),
  secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1
  pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./keys/example.pfx")),
  passphrase: PASSPHRASE
};

console.log('Run on https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```